# How is USB debugging mode related to root detection?

Tags: root-access, usb-debugging

I have a game in my Samsung Galaxy S2 (i9100) that if it detects the phone is rooted, it terminates. My phone is rooted but I still can play this game using OTA RootKeeper to temporarily unroot the phone.

I would like to use some apps that required USB debugging mode enabled when I play the game, however, the game terminates as if it detects the phone is rooted.

I have some friends that they can play the game with USB Debugging mode enabled (although their phones are not rooted). So I bet it's because USB debugging mode enabled would do something affecting root detection.

How does the USB debugging mode enabled affect root detection and how to solve that?