# How can an app detect ADB being used (e.g. with HttpToolkits)?

Tags: applications, adb, security

I have an app that stops working (at the login screen) when I have my device connected via ADB using HttpToolkits to get traffic. It seems odd; how does the app know that the phone is being used with ADB?

Comment: *how does the app know that phone is being used via adb*? -- you get that answer by reverse engineering the APK. Alternatively, you can approximate your answer by looking/web searching for the tactics that makes an app be aware of USB debugging being enabled or activated.Your app is probably listening for an intent or parsing notification contents. We can't be sure though. // Also, it is not weird for an app to disable its functionality if it detects itself in an unfavorable environment. It is an annoying thing to do to the user though.

Comment: Possibly related (old question, not answered yet): [How is USB debugging mode related to root detection?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49335/44325)